# Number of elements in each dimension of image

Tags: python, image, dimensions

I want to give an input image to my python script, and find out the number of elements in each dimension of the input image. Is there any function in python which gives the number of elements in each dimension.

Comment: There is `len` which gives you number of elements in any collection. How do you load an image (what have you tried)?

Comment: my input is a jpg image,i want to get the number of elements in each dimension.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'element in a dimension'

Comment: sorry,i mean the dimensions. width and height

Answer (score 0):

With scipy:

```
>>> from scipy.misc import imread
>>> img = imread("test.jpg")
>>> img.shape
0: (963, 712, 3)
```

Where 963 - width, 712 - height, 3 - number of channels.